# LibGDX TileMap problem

Tags: java, libgdx, tilemap

my LibGDX map find olny two Layers but the map.tmx file contains more than two layers. Where is the problem?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" tiledversion="2018.06.01" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="176" height="112" tilewidth="64" tileheight="64" infinite="0" nextlayerid="101" nextobjectid="6">
 <tileset firstgid="1" source="D:/Java/ETMP/core/assets/system/tiles01.tsx"/>
 <group id="99" name="Rooms">
  <layer id="4" name="Raum01" width="176" height="112" visible="0" offsetx="-48" offsety="72">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="65"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="71"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="0"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="23"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   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
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="5" name="Raum02" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="7"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="32"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3XMQqAMBBFwXgcF72F9z+TBlKIBEmlLs7AJylTvCalAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE+bL9tOd/i62mkcW9u5tFO/ZFA7nTrTLxnol8z0S2b6JbP6V+v1G28+CgbFzQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADgr3a+cw7jADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="6" name="Raum03" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="7"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="14"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="32"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3XMQqAMBBFwXgcF629gPc/kwlYiASxMysz8CHlFq9JKQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMAo5tv2yxtG1zqNc1vdUrcW/ZJD63TqTL9koF8y0y+Z6ZfM2r+t1298eRS8FA8DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgL87ADmDOgkANAEA
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="7" name="Raum04" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="7"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="20"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="32"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3XMQqAMBBFwXgcF/UU3v9MJmAhEsTOrMzAJylTvCalAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKObb9svdxhd63St2+qibjlP/ZJB63TqTL9koF8y0y+Z6ZfM2l+t1298+Sh4KR4GAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH9xAPR30mwANAEA
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="8" name="Raum05" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="7"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="26"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="32"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3XMQqAMBREwXgcg97C+58pBlKIBLHThRlY+GWK16QUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAINV623G54e96p3VsP7eNW78k6J0uk+mXBPolmX5Jpl+S9b/arN/65aPgpfowAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEjTAFPZhJIANAEA
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="9" name="Raum06" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="7"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="40"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="32"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3XQQqAIBRFUVtOn9pF+19TCQ4iJJzZp3PgoUMHd2IpAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwN+sjx23O3xd7TSu7e3c2qlfMqidLp3plwz0S2b6JTP9kln9q/X6jZmPgkHxMgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACY5QRHsSNxADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="10" name="Raum07" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="7"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="46"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="32"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3XMQqAMBBFwXgcF72F9z+TBlOIhGAjujADH7ZM8ZqUAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHCab9suN/xd7TTa1mNLu/VLBrXTqTP9koF+yUy/ZKZfMqt/tV6/8eWj4KEYDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADetgPkk/TNADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="11" name="Raum08" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="7"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="52"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="32"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3XQQqAIBRFUVtOUrto/2uqDw4iRBwE9eEceOjQwZ1YCgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMDY+thxu8PfRaf7tdq2tVO/ZBCdLp3plwz0S2b6JTP9kln81Xr91i8fBZPqYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwlhO9ZNIAADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="12" name="Raum09" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="7"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="58"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="32"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3XMQqAMBBFwXgcF72F9z+TBlKIBIk2ujADn6RM8ZqUAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPDOfNl2usPf1U7j2NrOpZ36JYPa6dSZfslAv2SmXzLTL5nVv1qv3/jyUTAobgYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT+3na4WDADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="13" name="Raum10" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="7"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="64"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="32"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3XMQqAMBBFwXgcF72F9z+TBlKIxGAh6MIMfNgyxWtSCgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMC75su20w1/VzuNtvXY0m79kkHtdOpMv2SgXzLTL5npl8zqX63Xb3z5KHgoBgMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAOzuP/CmDADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="14" name="Raum11" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="24"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="23"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="25"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="0"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3ZwQqCQBSG0dvjJBUtKtoO9P7PlAMGEunCTL10DvzQIC2Cj0EoYh37bo9u/fPQM9iC2uKpXWl36FZ65/Lh2TE0zDbUDncTpl+2QL9kVRus7wNT+i2hYdZT27vHtHZfO4eGWcfU9wbvEWyBfslMv2SmX7Kqzd1inn6voWGWNdfd6w5mDfolM/2SmX7J6pv/jIdWQsMsY+671x3MkvRLZvolM/2SmX7JTL9k1sRv+m2W/BH8rWZkl279z+/nse8DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAmCdW3izlADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="15" name="Raum12" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="10"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="22"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="39"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YsQrCMBQF0Pg5ZtDJ6tDFUfD/v8cXyBBKh1JsMHgOXGiTviFw6ZCUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADgd5wPCvRQuvaI3CO3yDOSa16Ra92b6v5U13KTMnNpvtVfeildO305+ksv+svI5qS/jMv/l5HpLyM7or/vrifgn5X7r2X/8sYsZ9pn6GGtl3tm194BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYKsP4zIVSQA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="16" name="Raum13" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="10"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="4"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="29"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="39"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3UMQqAMBBFwfU4pvECNvbe/zwaEJQ0IVVYmYHfb/HYCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA+Le1GWRSm93uHaFf8qnNLs/0Szbffs/Jt8Ao/5fM9Etm+iWzPfRLXiXefsvkW2BUaQYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPRd0Hhk0ADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="17" name="Raum14" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="27"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="23"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="40"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="39"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3asWrDMBCAYfVxYkjSpW6HLtnz/s9THaTUuLJCvPgE3wdHIemQ4UdcYpUCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD8Ou0cyCBavNb5qPNe51bns85c51L+ep0f781Fv+QRLb51Jto+r17TL1k867c1+iUL/TKyPf3eD/mk8J/zl5FNj+m1um5cv2Sz1bB+GcXUGP0ysmg1nmvolxG1vt95pswoWv0ud4v4ey76JafW/rs8h7fOZMggWox7O8/6jf+J+z7Xol/y6D3f6J3LkMGr/dohyOS7bPf71Xgt7g7HLqFfMthzP8IOQRb6ZWS938/0S3bRYey0r/Y7HfFhYaV39rbu+ywHjtbrF7Lb6tf5ygjW99rtBozETgsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAx/sBMpP7cQA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="18" name="Raum15" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="23"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="18"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="53"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="39"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3asQrCMBRA0fg5FqmbOrgIjv7/99hgu4g1oR3yAufAQxAHh0t4NE0JAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADY41g5EFFu8zbPZZrHNOPXd/olqtzmoTD6Jarafu0RRFTT7zhP/u0zaZk47qnc7zJ5Nz7Nn/olgprz999OAS1t7fea7MW0t7XfZS/WLy3t6TfPMA+0kNvbuv8OSb+0NayMOw16pl96VjqLvd9DL371e06fZ2juMojOLkHP9EvPSs8jXu3+GlRx/tIz/dIz/dKz0jsQENnaPbP3HwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABY8wYM0JCqADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="19" name="Raum16" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="9"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="62"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="39"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3WsQrCMBSG0evjNENdirp27/s/j1cwICiiQkmC58BH1gw/IREAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMDepg+CXt32OWeX7Jit9/OUncN+6VvJDm+yX3pWHnq1363d1eArSzxv2fvLiOyXkdU3uLS+CPyo/iUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAODfXQHEJtBzADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="20" name="Raum17" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="9"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="10"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="47"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YMQqEMBRF0bgcLZxGtLZ3/+uZfMZCRFQsnATOgdekSnFJkZQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAN7XHgxKdNRqbM6b8sakX8oVbUanffq1Gt1+8prN9Eupos3mYvqlVPqlZnf6Xf52Ozjn/aVm+3+HYZ3/M2rQ7XZ1DgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPPcFPoWGpwA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="21" name="Raum18" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="9"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="10"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="17"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="47"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YMQqAMBBFwfU4CnaKFjbe/1ImaBUUS12Ygd+kfqTYCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACA7/UPgwxqq0PZXDaW7aFn8qhtds1qz0ucTa+hX/7rrt92+uWv9EtmW+iXvPy/ZNbeGaZr7g9kMDR7ewcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAO4du5181gA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="22" name="Raum19" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="24"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="23"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="26"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="48"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3bMUvDQBzG4ax+lIhjRx0ERxfrZDup3/87eIEEQrjABXJ3/PF54IW2SYbCj5JSOgwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEBtY+HeDpy7DGqbOnuc97p6vN3Tzuvba5bn+qWFqbOHCtMvLeiXyJZ7Vf0SkX6JbPn+pl8icv9LZLX6fW/5Jvi3fP4S2fNwTqv6pYeXoazRj7Rr2mfmmH7ppfT+4SvtlnbPHNMvvZT2+532k/abOaZfejnj+5t+6UW/RHZGv7nf7/RLC2f0m5vfL2ihVr8+f2lBv0SmXyLTL5GNhbvMKz1fv7Sw93/j7Y6ev74GAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAyPsD2+NVcgA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="23" name="Raum20" width="176" height="112">
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQ0PoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB4NvNbsc4ANAEA
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="24" name="Raum21" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="6"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="4"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="70"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="54"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3SsQnAMAxFQWUcm4yQJpD9Z4oNKtymiRHcwUOtih8BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8K+WPXmhkrnZe3SG/VLPNToy+6WauVn7paq21Df/Al/1JQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAYK8XUlk2ZQA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="25" name="Raum22" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="43"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="9"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="70"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="23"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3dsYrCQBRA0fFzFBYslG1stvf/v0eDEbYQtXOunAOPtCkuQwjJzBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAt9q+MTCrpc/jdf6us1+vv+v1Z+iXuS19bp6MfpmZfinTL2WnoV+6rL+U6Zcy/VKmX8pe9Xv+3K3BS9ZfyvRLmX4p0y9l+qVMv5TplzL9Uub7M8qsv5TplzL9UqZfyvRLmX4p0y9l+qVMv5TplzL9UnbfI/UwHresX2a2W2ehX8r0S5l+qfl/TsDyHKFfSu7dPmpXv8zO/lGUef9LmX4p8/8mZc4vpGz3xgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANxfRb6BEADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="26" name="Raum23" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="6"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="9"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="62"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="61"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3WMQqAMAxA0XocBcFFdHBx9/7nMQXn2qlWeA8+XTOE0JQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIBWxoqgV3k/12iLluh83j2ak/2lb0c0FLq+Gw1e5fta2l/3l575//JnU0UAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALd276LcdADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="27" name="Raum24" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="19"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="16"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="47"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="61"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3asQrCMBRA0fRzLAhuOri4+//fY4oNhNpaDYIvcA68oVuHS3iBpAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPzSYWcgstLpKc8xz5jnNn/rl8hKu+c8w8rc//drsKneD6bzdq3dITl/iWO515Y9Yatd/RJF3ewlPXfbd93ql0hKv580q1+imTrc2xX0S1QtZ69+iaC+s+mX3tT3Nv3Sm2tq2x30SwStu69+icD+S8/GeVo61i9RLDvWLz0qDeuXXu29Wfd+ncjGLwYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAVw9sKwrYADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="28" name="Raum25" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="24"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="19"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="29"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="70"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3ZuwrCMACG0fg4Fm9L0cFFcPT9n8cUIpQOxZSYNnIO/CDo4PARqgkBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABYw35mz7S5z4wHtQ3dneNucY+4Lu4Ud407pHWjDe8d4y7p8316rV/WMHS3K7BX7S8OoVy/niFYQ6l+u6Bh6ruHMv1OG9YxNZQ6fz8bfgf2QcPUUbrf6VkMv5Tb77f/BTt/qWFJv13G4JeW9AtboV9apl9altuve2K2JPf+wvnLlnh+oGX6pWW59xH6ZUty7iLcSQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/7g0lmTN6ADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="29" name="Raum26" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="25"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="38"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="41"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="64"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3awWqDMAAG4OxxJuvqoWt32KWw93+mRRbBgzVZm7oEvg9+AlqJhx+VNCEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAK16LQi0aurne8wYc4w5x1xihphr0F/aNvXzZSP6S8v0l57pLz3TX3qmv/RMf+nZVn+t/9K6XH+H/7s1yNrq7xg8f2mb7196pr/0TH/ZS8lesXuTW4OY871yDErM6wHXNE45hN99Y5c0TnvJPtJ4TceO6XfnxfiZrs/1d96XNs/7tpj/EPSXcrl3/T3J9bfkeiihv/TsGf2dvgXGB67XX0p9hfr9rfH8hhLPeP7qL3up1d+/rJ/pL7XU7O+wiP6yh1v/PZw2ztXOaWU+KDHcyNa52lm7FwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIAafgBO8aL5ADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="30" name="Raum27" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="10"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="22"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="70"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YMQqAMBBFwXgcBcHGA9h7//OYQFqNjbgLM/BJm+KRIqUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABfmQeDyFqjR99at9dt/dQv0bVGp5vpl+j0S2b6JbOnfs8f7wVveH/JTL9k5v+XzJbBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIjpAne68hsANAEA
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="31" name="Raum28" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="17"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="15"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="63"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3asQrCMBQF0Pg5FkQnpy6Ogv//PRoaqUM16eR7cA7coZk6XB7hkVIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFseBQFS1n6dX7i3X9n1u0V8iq/08/Ij+Elmvv4///Rp0mb9kpr9k9t4x6C8ZjfTXXo2oPvu41d9LWfdpdbd2a2f6SwRTS+8e7F5BZL05rL9EtncO6y8RzUV/ycv8JbOtO/C3M4hm5D2l/S9RTTsCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQD5PsugrewA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="32" name="Raum29" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="9"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="11"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="16"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="63"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YsQqAIBiF0b/HsaUpWloae/8XSqGgKXRK4Ry4IM4fDkYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1EkNg96ULs+8497yOpf7NW8L/dKn0uVUMf3Soz30y7i8v4xMv4zs6TfFd8v6pUf+zxjZ3DAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADgHxesx/NoADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="33" name="Raum30" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="9"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="5"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="71"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3UMQqAMBBFwfU4EewtbOy9/3k0RUAljZVsmIHfb/HYCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEZWboNsardr6JecardT+MPk1Prdry2hX3Jp/bYd/54Dn2zx7Nf/JZP3/9UvmZTOIIu5MwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADGdQLnaaCeADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="34" name="Raum31" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="22"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="81"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YOwqAMBAFwHgcA3aKXkHw/ucxAQsR/DRigjPwCCkCKR5bbAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAvKm9CZQsd3ROGVKmlG47x6C/lC93tDmJ/lK6q/4uH/4LnjB/qZn+UrP9rqEP9g/UJe5yvMezRwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/tALo1ZwzADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="35" name="Raum32" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="30"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="22"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="87"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YQQrCMBAF0Hoci6VuNG4F738mp5BCKdkoYyXwHnzShDCrv2mGAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAnp03ee32WWnNhQxLl0rkGbnU9RaZIvfIHLluzuZ6vt571H2p36XemRpz1zn6S5alS6eDo79k0V96pr/0rPW/9U0fPw1k+MV7g/5ylPFPAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAyPYGLBj3fAA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="36" name="Raum33" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="13"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="21"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="51"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="87"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3ZMQrCMACG0XgcA9pO6uooeP/zmEAKGaPGpOB78KPQFhw+QsEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADgPccfDEbJva1p17RL2lI+H2X5+71cP1U7l+eW6rlb0C9j5d4OHadfRurZr/cHRuvZ7zMtjv35/Lle/Tp7maFnv85eRuvRr7OXWbb2vm3X2csMubtPG9Yue1A33NJyfZ922YNYreU/4u1e2JvYMAAAAAAAAAAAmOUFOhsYygA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="37" name="Raum34" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="11"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="32"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="69"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="85"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3ZsQrCMBQF0Pg5Fi0uVgeXgov//0MmmEKGDg0GUuUcuPS10EyXR6EhAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALDFsTKwJ6mT55h7zi3mkud0HWNeedZfeij35zOnfHbYmLV9vHaeXU1LqUtTzBxzyknzNXx269b+jvmduZiX86Z8v0R/aaVmx7aK/tJC7TeC/rInj5gh6C+/p9fu1V9aSB3qsXv1lxZq/020Dnxj6BwAAAAAAAAAAAAAgH/0BgmrQaQANAEA
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="38" name="Raum35" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="12"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="12"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="89"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="77"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3ZsQqDMBSG0fg4itoOQjt0Efr+z+QNZFRway49B74lOv5kSSkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwC+NF30vzqEndZPPaG89oiWaozV6R6/2j/3Sm7rJ4Wb2S2/sl8zsl8w+xX7Jy/1LZvZLZvZLZvZLZmdvbFvL+xu9m0668w0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD4DwclhpekADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="39" name="Raum36" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="9"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="12"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="78"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="78"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YsQqAIBiFUXucgqCpWhuD3v95UhCagpz6hXPgQ2hquDiYEgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPMbGIJKyySO35+bcmlvqudVvZz3tl2jKJoeP2S/R2C89a9nv9dM/whv3Lz2zX3rm/YyeTY0BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABDLDbsqEQAANAEA
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="40" name="Raum37" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="16"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="10"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="69"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="64"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3asQqDMABF0fRzKnRr0dWx0P//niagi9jq1rxyDrwlk8Mlg6QUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACDV9cSgV63Pedmjbqp71t3qxqJf+tb6vHyZfunZUb+v330aHHL/kky/JNMvyfRLqvX/rn5J1Nocin7J1Np1/5JMvyTTL8n0S7LtW7P7zhn0atjs0xkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAv3kD9lx88wA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="41" name="Raum38" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="10"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="35"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="78"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="70"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YzQqCQBQG0OlxEn9aZLUN3PT+L9QIdyGhoQNSwjnwgXMdx823mpQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADKnCcZPtZ7ZFj4D5QYu3PJ6XPqnFc8P2LexrqN2fj+lvOMdTP5/j7Z18e+LvY28VxH2tjfJf2l3Nid04+jv5TSX45Mfzky/eXI/qW/OkyJLf1duhO7LszXnlsl/aXM1vvbaiZpZlZyNwxbzfXxW/Y6d8vZAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGu8Ae1J1IoANAEA
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="42" name="Raum39" width="176" height="112">
   <properties>
    <property name="height" type="int" value="8"/>
    <property name="width" type="int" value="13"/>
    <property name="x" type="int" value="78"/>
    <property name="y" type="int" value="64"/>
   </properties>
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3YOwqDQBQF0MlyEoKkUNOkEWyE7H89ecIERFSwcpRz4DKfaorLFC8lAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOCq7gvpV+7/gVKMfXxFhkib98+8viNVpIs0+U5/KcnYx9uO6C8l+aR9/f0e80xY5P/lzPSXM5vOFeq0PXcwf6A0j0nm57UAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADAUX672uqLADQBAA==
  </data>
  </layer>  
 </group>
 <group id="100" name="Mobel">
  <layer id="51" name="Mobel1" width="176" height="112">
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3WuwqAMAwFUH/Z0dEHiA/wl+1gF6GUgkWUc+BSkkDI2KYBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA4Av6kKHi/jZT3++I7xgyVbyLf1hC1or7u0x9vyO+W8he8S6At8xXUrOSfpT6G8DTjiupWUk/Sv0NAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAvuQEW28wMAA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="52" name="Mobel2" width="176" height="112">
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3OMQ5AQBRF0VmmhmiInVChsl5T/85E8iPOSV7xulsKAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADQqq8bsiOg0VQ3Z0cAAAAAn7WFv6dUQJsz/CulAt7RZQfAA2v4Y0YENDrCX1IqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAv7sBhH0cyAA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="53" name="Mobel3" width="176" height="112">
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3OIQ6AMBBE0V6YOrgCNU0x3JfVlQ3Jir6XfDFuSgEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAfxxRje7sI7DgjK5oZB8B2Eyfdkt5AWveaT8pLwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgF18yTGdegA0AQA=
  </data>
  </layer>
  <layer id="54" name="Mobel4" width="176" height="112">
   <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAACu3OMQqAMAAEwXxYIYWCP7D0yUmdziA5kBm44rotBQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADWqukAeOEe/hWpgDlPOgA+svXt6QiYdPSd6QgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOAXGuMU5/0ANAEA
  </data>
  </layer>
</map>
```

Comment: [Validate your XML](https://validator.w3.org/check).